# How to smoothly change between vastly different melodies

Tags: composition, melody, orchestration

I'm starting a Concerto(Piano) and all of the problems I have come across are A: regarding the orchestration(this is my first orchestral piece) and B: the 2 subjects of the first sonata movement are very different in terms of tempo(The concerto starts in 120 bpm, the first subject is just four whole notes, the second is syncopated quarter and 8th notes) so when I attempt the modulation from the slow opening with the first subject(diatonic with chromatic harmony) to the faster 2nd subject(chromatic with less chromatic harmony) it seems sudden and abrupt. I have tried everything I could think of to lighten the modulation to the 2nd subject, but no matter what I do, it is always abrupt and does not work. How do you create transitions between very different subjects?

Comment: It's your concerto, so you have to decide how you want to solve issues like that.  Without seeing what you have, I can't comment much, but I'd probably do the modulation slow, end on a fermata, and then let 'er rip for the 2nd.  Be like Beethoven-- make the abruptness a feature.

Comment: There are hundreds of concerti out there, written by the famous names and more. Listen to lots and copy what you like.

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'answer' to your question.  But let me throw some ideas at you.

If your second subject doesn't grow organically out of the first subject it might be the wrong one for THIS sonata.  But 'sudden and abrupt' is good too.  Just try to choose two themes that are in the same ballpark - that CAN follow one another in the same musical flow.

(Maybe what you've written so far is a slow introduction and a first subject?)

'Just four whole notes'.  That might describe the thematic germ of the first subject, in the same way as 'just an appeggio plus a twiddle' describes the germ of Beethoven's Piano Sonata op.2 no.1 (and if you're attempting a sonata-form movement and haven't studied that piece, drop everything and do it NOW!)   But you've got to turn that into at least a couple of pages of music if it's going to be worth the musicians turning up!  And it can't ALL be whole notes.